# pywikipedia logging in?

Tags: python, authentication, pywikibot

For various reasons I can't use login.py to log me in so I was wondering if anyone knew code so that I could log in to Wikipedia with my script without running a separate script?
Cheers!

Comment: please, specify what script, maybe show the code behind the login.py script and specify what's the actual problem? :) and what does "can't use" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is going to be simple: you can't use pywikipedia without being able to run `login.py`.

That file not only provides a nice User-interface to try your configuration: it contains all the authentication primitives that we use in the framework to log in. Without logging-in, you can't do much, so no.

If you want a more helpful answer, you'll have to be more precise: as in, why you can't use login.py, and what operations you do need to do with Pywikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative that worked for me, when I wasn't able to interactively use my remote server (and thus not enter my password), was to copy my credentials to the remote server.

By default your remote permissions are stored in `~/.pywikibot/pywikibot.lwp`, and it has worked for me in the past to log in locally, then copy this `.lwp` file to the remote server, and then I no longer had to enter my password on the remote server.

I don't claim this method to be secure at all, but it is a hack.

Comment: Any idea how `~/.pywikibot/pywikibot.wp` gets created?  That directory exists but is empty in my pywikibot installation on Fedora 23.

Comment: @wallyk, `~/.pywikibot/pywikibot.lwp` is a cookie file, and is created once you successfully log in. If you haven't logged in yet, you probably don't have a `.lwp`.

Comment: Indeed, I logged in months ago and have run a pywikibot script every day.  Just a few days ago it prompted for the password again.  I was looking for a way to persistently satisfy it, perhaps by putting the password in a config file.